# Is it possible to create waterfallseries3D chart in JS API?

Tags: lightningchart

I am considering to buy a license of Lightning Chart for Javascript.

I am satisfied the performance but I wonder I can implement waterfallseries3D chart using JS API

I cannot find waterfallseries3D chart in the API Document.

Could I Implement it using other types of chart?

Thank you.

Comment: To receive an answer sooner, please elaborate on the details and requirements of "water fall series 3D". Picture tells more than a hundred words.

Answer (score 0):

By waterfall series 3D do you mean a chart like in this image?

[image]

This kind of chart can be created by creating a [SurfaceMeshSeries3D](https://www.arction.com/lightningchart-js-api-documentation/v3.0.1/classes/surfacemeshseries3d.html) for each frequency.

`SurfaceMeshSeries3D` creates a grid (columns x rows) where each cell coordinate can be positioned freely in 3D coordinates (x, y, z).

Here is a code snippet for visualizing one of the depicted frequencies (50 Hz).

```js
const {
  lightningChart,
  emptyFill,
  SurfaceSeriesTypes3D,
  SolidFill,
  SolidLine,
  ColorRGBA,
} = lcjs

const {
createProgressiveTraceGenerator,
createSpectrumDataGenerator
} = xydata

const chart = lightningChart().Chart3D()
.setTitleFillStyle(emptyFill)

const timeSamples = 500
const frequency = 50

const mesh = chart.addSurfaceSeries({
type: SurfaceSeriesTypes3D.Mesh,
columns: timeSamples,
rows: 2,
start: { x: 0, z: 0 },
end: { x: 100, z: 100 },
pixelate: false
})
.setFillStyle(new SolidFill({ color: ColorRGBA(255, 63, 27) }))

chart.getDefaultAxisZ().setInterval(40, 60, false, true)

createSpectrumDataGenerator()
.setSampleSize(timeSamples)
.setNumberOfSamples(1)
.setVariation(3)
.generate()
.toPromise()
.then(data => {
    data = data[0]
    mesh.invalidateGeometryOnly((row, column) => ({
        x: column,
        y: row === 0 ? 0 : data[column],
        z: frequency
    }))
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/xydata@1.4.0/dist/xydata.iife.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@arction/lcjs@3.0.0/dist/lcjs.iife.js"></script>
```

If you want to visualize the outline stroke, then I suggest using `LineSeries3D`.